# No activity found to handle Intent - android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-4.4-kitkat, storage-access-framework

I am trying my hand on Storage Access Framework of android 4.4

I have developed a dummy app which fires an intent on start of the activity.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Also I have developed another dummy app which serves as the file-provider.

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.saf"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="19"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.saf.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <provider
        android:name="com.example.saf.MyFileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.saf.documents"
        android:exported="@bool/is_kitkat"
        android:enabled="@bool/is_kitkat"
        android:grantUriPermissions="@bool/is_kitkat"
        android:permission="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.content.action.DOCUMENTS_PROVIDER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </provider>

</application>
```

I have implemented the class MyFileProvider.

But when I launch the user-app (the one which fires the intent), I get the following error

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT cat=[android.intent.category.OPENABLE] }
```

I was just following developer docs of android. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Edit:
Here is my latest Manifest. 
Also do I need to have a "proper" implementation of the MyFileProvider "extends DocumentsProvider"? Can I just return null in the functions for now?

Comment: Does your dummy app uses-permission `android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS`?

Comment: @SherifelKhatib - actually it did not have that permission. but i added it and checked. still the same error.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Add a mime type, or simply `intent.setType("*/*")`.

This seems to be a [known issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63550). `setType()` is required.

Edit: you also need to add `android:enabled="true"`, note that you should reference it from values and not directly so as only to enable it for >=kitkat. So `android:enabled="@bool/is_kitkat"`, `<bool name="atLeastKitKat">false</bool>` in `/res/values/` and `<bool name="atLeastKitKat">true</bool>` in `/res/values-v19/`

Comment: it worked! but still i cannot see the my host app which is working as the provider.

Comment: still not able to see my host app which is working as the provider.

Answer (score 8):

To open all files add this line:

```
intent.setType("*/*") ;
```

and if you need to filter to display images add this line:

```
intent.setType("image/*");
```

Answer (score -1):

Just cast your intent, 
like,

```
     Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT");
    ((Intent)intent).addCategory("android.intent.category.OPENABLE");
    ((Intent)intent).setType("*/*");
```

Comment: Lots of unecessary casting.... you might as well just write `new Intent("android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT").addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE).setType("*/*");` and get the same result, with much less operations