# No Activity found to handle Intent CREATE_DOCUMENT

Tags: android

My crash reporting tool reports a frequent error, mostly on Xiaomi devices on Android 5.0.2:
`Fatal Exception: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.CREATE_DOCUMENT cat=[android.intent.category.OPENABLE] typ=application/pdf (has extras) }
       at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1765)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1602)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivityFromFragment(Activity.java:4391)
       at android.app.Fragment.startActivityForResult(Fragment.java:1100)
       at android.app.Fragment.startActivityForResult(Fragment.java:1084)`

Is there any reason why these devices would not support SAF? And how could I work around this in a proper way?

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21045091/no-activity-found-to-handle-intent-android-intent-action-open-document) you need to set

```
intent.setType("*/*");
```

or in your case probably

```
intent.setType("application/pdf")
```

for the crash to go away.

Comment: Your solution should be marked as correct.

Answer (score 3):

First thing you can do is to avoid the crash -

```
       if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                context.startActivity(intent);
            } else { 
    Toast.makeToast(context, "No application found on device to open view", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() 
}
```

Comment: This answer is better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57453337/11004423