# Does android.intent.action.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE still require setType()?

Tags: android, android-intent, storage-access-framework

The following code with setType() as explained by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21045263/355456) worked fine until recently?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
intent.setType("*/*");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_OPEN_DIRECTORY);
```

Now, this code throws ActivityNotFoundException on Android emulators and physical devices that I have tested.   I am not sure if it throws ActivityNotFoundException on all devices.   Unfortunately, I do not know which change of the dev environment has caused this.  If setType() is taken out, it works fine on all tested emulators and physical devices.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_OPEN_DIRECTORY);
```

Could anyone shed some light on the current status for the requirement of setType()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is taken from [DocumentsUI manifest in Android 10](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DocumentsUI/+/refs/heads/android10-release/AndroidManifest.xml):

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />
    <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
</intent-filter>

<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

The intent filter for the directory picker doesn't define any mime type. That means that for the activity to open your intent can't have any explicit mime type, including `*/*`.

Keep mime type `null`. You're picking a directory. Directories don't have a meaningful mime type.

The post you were referring to is about `OPEN_DOCUMENT` which does require explicit mime type.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.   I had the same problem as the post for ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE, so I added intent.setType("*/*") to avoid that. That was one or two years ago. As stated, I do not know when it stopped working.  One possibility is that it happened to work on the devices that I used for testing, and I did not test on devices that would not work.

Answer (score 1):

use `resolveActivity` before `startActivity` to avoid `ActivityNotFoundException`

```
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) = null) {
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_OPEN_DIRECTORY);
}
```

Comment: This has the unfortunate side-effect that the directory picker doesn't open. That being said it really is a good practice before starting activities that may not be there, like camera intent on devices with no camera.