# No activity found to handle Intent - android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT while using Fragment

Tags: android, android-intent

i have a problem with my android app; i want to add a document from storage of smartphone; i am in a fragment, it could be the problem but i don't know how to solve it.

```
private void selectFile(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    startActivityForResult(intent,READ_REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == READ_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        if(data != null){
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            filePath = uri.getPath();
        }
    }
}
```

I have also this to request permission:

```
if( ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        requestPermissions(new String[]{ Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},PERMISSION_REQUEST_STORAGE);
    }
```

but it also said to me:

> No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT }

How can i solve it?

Comment: make sure your device has some application for reading documents...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No activity found to handle Intent - android.intent.action.OPEN\_DOCUMENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21045091/no-activity-found-to-handle-intent-android-intent-action-open-document)

Answer (score 0):

if device version is greater then `Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT` then use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` otherwise use `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`

`ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` use only if `API Level 19` or latest. Otherwise Use `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` on older devices.